# React native + IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native

As a beginner in the React native framework.  I was able to build a small app and install it on my iOS physical device via Xcode. But this app doesn't work when I'm away from my laptop.

Is there any way I can always run this app on my device on 7/24 even when I'm away from the network and my laptop (Without publishing it in the app store)?

Personal app and I need it on my device only.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on project then on menus open "product" > schema >edit schema then change build configuration "debug" to release.
[image: edit schema]
Now run your project. It will run even after you are away from laptop.